# Получить координаты элемента path из svg файла

Tags: svg

Как получить координаты элемента path из svg файла? У меня куча скопированных элементов, различающихся лишь полями `transform` и `id`. Здесь нарисован круг, мне нужно получить его координаты и радиус.

```
<path
   transform="translate(5212.8026,1862.7082)"
   sodipodi:type="arc"
   style="fill:#ffff00;stroke:#00ff00;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
   id="path3949-2"
   sodipodi:cx="-755.27716"
   sodipodi:cy="2237.8789"
   sodipodi:rx="78.77124"
   sodipodi:ry="74.137634"
   d="m -676.50592,2237.8789 a 78.77124,74.137634 0 1 1 -157.54248,0 78.77124,74.137634 0 1 1 157.54248,0 z" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Впишите круг в квадрат... Узнайте его координаты и поделите его сторону пополам. Получите радиус. В вашем случае, нужно еще уточнить откуда идет вычисление координат круга?
От центра круга или от левого верхнего края описанного квадрата?!
Вот вам радиус: [Радиус вписанной окружности в квадрат](http://www-formula.ru/index.php/2011-09-22-03-32-27).
Нашел ссылочку по `xhtml`: [Карты ссылок](http://inter-vuz.tuit.uz/Elib_baza//INTUIT.ru/html/department/internet/xhtml/7/8.html).